# How can I bookmark Info page to continue reading later?

Tags: info, bookmarks

How can I bookmark Info page to continue reading later ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some bookmarking commands to get you started:

- `C-x r m` – set a bookmark at the current location (e.g. in a file)
- `C-x r b` – jump to a bookmark
- `C-x r l` – list your bookmarks
- `M-x bookmark-delete` – delete a bookmark by name

Courtesy of [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks)

Comment: Sake: Note that these commands are not *specific* to Info nodes. Bookmarks are a very general facility.